# Unique ID for sentence

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am givin hundreds of text snippets in all different languages(unicode). I need to assign a unique ID to each sentence so I can train a ML algorithm. I wrote my own algorithm and there were roughly 30k duplicate numbers. I then found this solution:

```
def remapWord(word):
    return int.from_bytes(word.encode(), 'little')
```

but apparently the int is too big for numpy, it throws a

`ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').`

When I try to fit the data. Is there another way to get a unique ID or prevent the valueerror from occuring?

Comment: Why not just enumerate the sentences (i.e. give them numbers from 1 to N)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import hashlib 
def remap(word):
    h = hashlib.md5()
    h.update(word)
    return int(h.hexdigest(), 16))
```